# Use ip address for name server and have it dedicated to a single site

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, web-hosting, ip-address, reverse-dns

Ok so I think I have this setup right but I just want to be sure. I have 3 IP address:

1.1.1.1 also known as ns1
2.2.2.2 also known as ns2
3.3.3.3 also known as ns3

They are being used as NameServers for my server. I also dedicated them out to clients as follows.

1.1.1.1 Shared Hosting with Multiple Clients
2.2.2.2 My Sites all live here
3.3.3.3 Client that requires a dedicated IP

Is there an issue or conflict with using my name server IP's and dedicating them to a specific site only?

Are they working as they should when a DNS request is processed for NS2 for customers who live on the NS1 IP?

Also I should specify that I have instructed my clients to use all 3 NameServers for their domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no issue as a Dedicated IP setup is only for software E.G Apache 2.
I quite often do this myself.

Comment: Awesome I thought so I just wanted to make sure it was not an issue and that I wasn't missing anything. Thank you.